# How do I change from json to a prettyprintjson renderer depending on params passed in?

Tags: python, pyramid

I have a url, call it example.com that returns a json-formatted string. I'd like to be able to pass in a parameter that lets me pretty print this json so it's more readable. I've read through [the docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/renderers.html) but something isn't sinking in for me.
Here's what I have:

```
# config
config.add_renderer('prettyprintjson', JSON(indent=4))

# view
@view_config(route_name='home',renderer='prettyprintjson')
def home(request):
  if request.params.get('pretty') == 'true': return {'name':'Fred'} # pretty print
  else: return {'name':'Fred'} # how do I return a non-pretty print version???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution for your case:

```
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='json')
# It's better to keep non-pretty JSON renderer as a default one
def home(request):
   if request.params.get('pretty'):
       request.override_renderer = 'prettyprintjson'
   return {'name':'Fred'}
```

More info in the [Overriding A Renderer At Runtime](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/renderers.html#overriding-a-renderer-at-runtime) section of docs.

Comment: I saw that section but they made it look much, much harder than it needed to be. Thanks for simplifying! Will accept when the timer here lets me.